# Two "form action's" on one line

Tags: html, css, forms, action

I have just finished putting a login and register bit on my website and now I'm just cleaning things up, but then I came to this problem I have two form action's on one page, each one goes to a different page, easy enough, but I can't seem to get them both on one line.

Here is the code for the form actions:

```
<form action='logout.php' method='POST'>           
<input type='submit' value='Logout' />      
</form>                      
<form action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>     
<input type='submit' value='Change password' />       
</form>
```

I've tried

```
<form action='logout.php' method='POST'>           
<input type='submit' value='Logout' />                           
<form action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>     
<input type='submit' value='Change password' />       
</form>
```

but both buttons go to the same location

the website is [www.crossception.com](http://www.crossception.com), you will need to login to get to this problem 
I've already made a login and password for every one to use
username : stackoverflow
password : test101

thank you very much
connor
(aged 15)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<span style="float:left;">
    <form action='logout.php' method='POST'>           
        <input type='submit' value='Logout' />      
    </form>   
</span>
<span style="float:right;">
    <form action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>     
        <input type='submit' value='Change password' />       
    </form>
</span>
```

Comment: Quick way if you don't want to deal with using separate CSS just yet. If this will be common to many pages, you may want to pull out the styling to its on section.

Comment: rachel, i have another problem, well not problem, more of an irritation, im guessing you have been to the website and logged in and noticed that it says "Welcome, Stackoverflow" on the top right hand side, i would now like that to be on the same line as the two buttons, now the welcome message is php, is that a problem?

Comment: should i ask that on another question?

Comment: Ask in another question. I don't know PHP that well. Sorry

Comment: You can do the first (left) span as "<span style="float:left;">", the second (middle) span as "<span>" and the third (right) span as "<span style="float:right;">"

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question properly, I think you need to use some CSS:

```
form {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

You might want to add a class to those forms to stop yourself styling all forms like this

Comment: thanks james, where do i add that, at the begging of both the actions or at the start of one of them. and how to i add some class (still getting use to html)

Comment: Your form tags want to look something like `<form action="..." method="..." class="floatLeft">` - replace the "..." with the parts of the tag that you already have. The first line of the CSS I posted should change from `form {` to `.floatleft {` and it should go in a separate style sheet, linked in your head tag

Comment: so it look a little like                        
*** form {
<form ation="..." method="...." class="floatleft"> **
<input type='submit' value='Logout' /> **
</form>
{ ****, im not very good a stackoverflow

Comment: No, not much like that. Your opening form tags (the bits that start `<form action=`) would simply gain another attribute: `class="floatLeft"`. In HTML, a tag is anything between `<` and `>`, so in your first example you had 2 `form` tags and 2 `input` tags. Attributes are the extra pieces of information in those tags, in the form `key="value"`, so in your first `form` tag you had the attributes `action` and `method`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the dirty inline version

```
<form action='logout.php' method='POST' style='float:left;'>           
<input type='submit' value='Logout' />      
</form>                      
<form action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>     
<input type='submit' value='Change password' />       
</form>
```

Of course James's suggestion to use a class is the proper way to do it.

Btw, those forms should be **after** the opening body tag.