# second form action attribute not working

Tags: css, http

I have 2 form action below and whenever I click the 2nd form action (post /logout), the first action (get /journey) get triggered.

```
<form action="/journey" method="get"><input type="submit" value="Journey" />
<form action="/logout" method="POST"><input type="submit" value="Logout" />
```

The second action works if I didn't add in the /journey action.

Anyone can tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the problem is you're trying to nest html forms, which doesn't work. If you want to be able to differentiate which button was pressed in your server-side form handler, you can add a name="button_pressed" attribute to each submit button. Then your form handler will see button_pressed=Journey or button_pressed=Logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try after closing form tags as shown below :

```
  <div style="float:left"> 
   <form action="/journey" method="get">
       <input type="submit" value="Journey" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form action="/logout" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, You are right. After closing the form tag, the buttons are now stacked in 2 lines. It was initially on one line. Is there anyway to have them on one line?

Comment: I got the answer from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486853/two-form-actions-on-one-line

Comment: @revolver yes you have to  make use of div check my edited answer might help you

Comment: @revolver  - thna you should upvote and accept answer if it works for you